# Crossrider extension on browser launch

Tags: google-chrome-extension, php-extension, safari-extension, browser-extension, crossrider

I Need to make a homepage extension. My idea is to host the page on server and redirect the browser to that page on the launch of browser only. Can some one help me to create extension for this using crossrider.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Crossrider platform does not support changing/redirecting the browser home page as this is an annoyance to users. The nearest you can get to it, is to create the tab with the desired page, as follows:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.tabs.create('http://www.example.com');
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Thank you @Shlomo for the guidance. Adopting this way to work around